# Cadastro de usuario em NodeJS e Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api

Estou desenvolvendo uma api para o meu TCC, preciso fazer um sistema de cadastro de usuários e de login.

```
router.post('/cadastro_usuarios', (req, res, next) => {
  const { cpf, email, nome, sobrenome, senha, dtnasci } = req.body;
  pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('Error ao adquirir o cliente', err.stack)
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = $1', [req.body.email],
      (err, result) => {
        release();
        if (err) {
          return console.error('Erro ao executar a query', err.stack);
        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(409).send({ mensagem: 'Usuário já cadastrado' })
          
        }
        else {
          bcrypt.hash(req.body.senha, 10, (errBcrypt, hash) => {
            if (errBcrypt) { return res.status(500).send({ error: errBcrypt }); }
            client.query('INSERT INTO usuario (cpf, email, nome, sobrenome, senha, dtnasci) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)',
              [req.body.cpf, email, nome, sobrenome, hash, dtnasci]);

            return res.status(201).send({
              mensagem: 'Usuário criado com sucesso',
              usuarioCriado: { cpf, email, nome, sobrenome, dtnasci }
            });
          });
          console.log("Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!");
        }
      })
  })
})
```

Ele não entra de forma alguma no if (result.length > 0) para retornar que determinado email existe, fora isso o cadastro funciona normalmente, no banco eu já deixei o email como UNIQUE então ele retorna um erro do próprio banco mas não retorna o erro que determinei na API, dei um console.log(result) e ele exibe a consulta com os resultados esperados.

Conexão com o banco:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
})

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('erro ao pegar o cliente', err.stack)
  }
  client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, result) => {
    release()
    if (err) {
      return console.error('erro ao executar a query', err.stack)
    }
    console.log('Conectado com sucesso', result.rows)
  })
})
```

Comment: Se estiver usando a lib pg. deveria verificar o length do `result.rows`

Comment: @Danizavtz fiz o que disse e funcionou, realmente algo tão besta que me fez quebrar a cabeça varias vezes, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso esteja utilizando a lib [`pg`](https://node-postgres.com/), isso acontece porque o resultado de uma consulta é um objeto. E não um array, isso é um comportamento documentado.

Então para acessar os valores do seu `SELECT`, você deve olhar o conteúdo do nó `rows` que está na variável `result` do seu código. É nesta variável que contém o resultado da consulta.

Segue um exemplo:

```
 client.query('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = $1', [req.body.email],
      (err, result) => {
        release();
        if (err) {
          return console.error('Erro ao executar a query', err.stack);
        }
        if (result.rows.length > 0) {
          res.status(409).send({ mensagem: 'Usuário já cadastrado' })
          
        }
}
```

### Porque está ocorrendo o erro?

O erro ocorre porque o resultado é um objeto (JSON) e não um array. Então não existe o atributo `length` neste objeto de retorno da lib pg.

O json de retorno possui o seguinte formato (pg versão 8.8.0):

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 123456789,
  oid: null,
  rows: [
    //...
  ],
  fields: [
    //...
  ],
  _parsers: [
    //...
  ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
   //...
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

Repare que este JSON de retorno é inválido (pois não é possível ter comentários em um JSON) estou utilizando apenas para exemplificar o objeto de retorno, para ter uma ideia do motivo de não funcionar.